# On the proof of the Khintchine-Kolmogorov Convergence Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let $(X_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of independent, mean-zero random variables with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\text{Var}(X_n) < \infty$.

This is about an intermediate step in the proof of the  Khintchine-Kolmogorov Convergence Theorem. Denote $S_j = X_1 + \cdots + X_j$. I have that for any $h > 0$, $$\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{i \geq 1}|S_{k + i} - S_k| \geq h \right) \leq \dfrac{1}{h^2}\sum_{j=k+1}^{\infty}\sigma^2_j$$ where $\sigma^2_j$ denotes the variance of $X_j$. How do you make the leap from this to $$\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{n, k \geq N}|S_{n} - S_k| \geq h \right) \leq \dfrac{2}{h^2}\sum_{j=N+1}^{\infty}\sigma^2_j$$
After sorting through nearly a dozen measure-theoretic probability books, I haven't seen this exact leap being made, but [Durrett](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3875846/proof-of-kolmogorov-convergence-theorem-in-durrett-ed5) is very close.

Here's my attempt: let's write
$$\sup_{n, k \geq N}|S_n - S_k|  = \sup_{n, k \geq N}|S_n - S_{k +i} + S_{k+i} - S_k| \leq \sup_{n, k \geq N}|S_{k + i} - S_n| + \sup_{n, k \geq N}|S_{k + i} - S_k|\text{.}$$
I'm not exactly sure how the $\sup_{n, k \geq N}$ get translated to $\sup_{i \geq 1}$ here, assuming this is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove  he inequality with a bigger constant on the right but that is good enough for proving the theorem.

$\sup_{n,k \geq N} |S_n-S_k| \geq h$ implies $\sup_{n \geq N} |S_n-S_N| \geq h/2$ or $\sup_{k \geq N} |S_k-S_N| \geq h/2$. Form this you get the required inequality with RHS repaced by $2\frac  1 {(h/2)^{2}} \sum\limits_{j=N}^{\infty} \sigma_j^{2}$ which means $\frac 2 {h^{2}}$ gets replaced by $\frac  {8} {h^{2}}$.

[$\sup_{n \geq N} |S_n -S_N| $ is same as $\sup_{i \geq 1}  |S_{N+i}-S_N|$].