# Average of Gaussian Converge to One almost Surely

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, normal-distribution

I am trying to solve for the following problem:

> Let $g_1, g_2, \cdots$ be i.i.d. standard Gaussian random variables. Let $(a_{ij})_{i < j}$ be in $\ell^2$ i.e. $\sum_{i < j} a_{ij}^2 < \infty$. Let $X_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1} ^n g_i^2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} a_{ij}g_ig_j$. Show that the sequence $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ converges to $1$ a.s.

I am really stuck on this problem and need some hints to at least move in the right direction. I am thinking this might be related to Komogorov's zero-one law, but my class has not covered the theorem. Any hints to help me move in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442472

Comment: @VezenBU I don't think that this would help though. It's not just the distributional properties of the sum of gaussians we are concerned it. We need to unwind those information into a statement about almost sure convergence. That's why either one requires notion of martingales or familiarity with the Kolmogorov Three Series Theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** By SLLN,

$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} g_i^2 \to \mathbf{E}[g_1^2] = 1 \qquad \text{a.s.} $$

**2.** Let $Y_n = \sum_{i < j \leq n} a_{ij} g_i g_j$, and let $\mathcal{F}_{n} = \sigma(g_i : i \leq n)$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $g_1,\ldots,g_n$. Then $(Y_n)$ is a $(\mathcal{F}_n)$-martingale, since

$$ \mathbf{E}[Y_{n+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_n] = Y_n + \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i,n+1} \mathbf{E}[g_i g_{n+1} | \mathcal{F}_n] = Y_n. $$

Moreover,

$$ \mathbf{E}[Y_n^2]
= \sum_{\substack{i < j \leq n \\ k < l \leq n}} a_{ij}a_{kl} \mathbf{E}[g_i g_j g_k g_l] $$

and only the summands with $(i, j) = (k, l)$ survives, yielding

$$ \mathbf{E}[Y_n^2] = \sum_{i < j  \leq n} a_{ij}^2 \leq \sum_{i<j} a_{ij}^2. $$

Therefore $(Y_n)$ is an $L^2$-martingale and hence converges a.s. by [Doob's martingale convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_convergence_theorems#Convergence_in_Lp). In particular, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} Y_n \to 0$.

Comment: Bravo Sangchul Lee.

Answer (score 3):

It is a result due to Kolmogorv and Khintchine that if $X_{n}$ is a sequence of independent random variables such that $\sum_{n}Var(X_{n})<\infty$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}X_{k}-E(X_{k})$ converges almost surely to some random variable which is finite almost surely. See [this question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3875846/proof-of-kolmogorov-convergence-theorem-in-durrett-ed5?noredirect=1&lq=1) for more.

A short sketch of the proof is given below.

> Well, the reason for the above is that if we WLOG assume that
> $E(X_{k})=0$ (else consider $X_{k}-E(X_{k})$) for each $k$, then
> $||S_{n}-S_{m}||_{L^{2}}=\sum_{k=n}^{m}Var(X_{k})\leq\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}Var(X_{k})
> > \xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$ .Which means that $S_{n}$ is $L^{2}$
> Cauchy. Now this is due to a theorem due to Levy that $S_{n}$ being
> Cauchy in probability implies it is Cauchy almost surely. (where
> $S_{n}$ is the sequence of partial sums of independent random
> variables).

Let $\displaystyle S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$

This idea is also similar to what Sangchul Lee's answer suggests. Basically, since $E(X_{k})=0$, then what we have shown implies $S_{n}$ is an $L^{2}$ Cauchy martingale which implies convergence to a random variable $X_{\infty}\in L^{1}$ and hence is finite almost surely.

Anyways, getting back to your problem,

First see that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1} ^n g_i^2\xrightarrow{a.s.}1 $ due to SLLN.

Next, your condition directly implies that $\sum_{i<j}Var( a_{ij}g_ig_j)=\sum_{i<j}a_{ij}^{2}<\infty$.

Hence  $\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} a_{ij}g_ig_j$ converges to an almost surely finite random variable due to the result I stated above.

Hence $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} a_{ij}g_ig_j\xrightarrow{a.s.}0$ easily follows.

For a more detailed reference to the Kolmogorov-Khintchine Criterion see [Sidney Resnick a Probability Path](https://bayanbox.ir/view/5388755611987847515/Sidney-Resnick-A-Probability-Path-BookFi.org.pdf) Theorem 7.3.3

Comment: Could you explain how you used the Kolmogorov-Khintchine Criterion without knowing $\{ g_ig_j \}_{i < j}$ is independent?

Answer (score 2):

I have only a partial answer. Denote $Y_n=X_n-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{1}^ng_i^2.$ From the strong law of large numbers $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{1}^ng_i^2$ converge to $1$ almost surely, but I am able to prove only that $Y_n$ tends to zero weakly as follows: clearly $E(Y_n)=0$ and $E(Y_n^2)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i<j<n}a^2_{ij}\to_{n\to \infty}0$ getting  the Tchebychev inequality $$\Pr(|Y_n|>\epsilon)\leq \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}E(Y_n^2);$$ this is not enough for using Borel Cantelli and getting almost sure convergence of $Y_n$ to $0.$

Comment: Actually, you can strenghten your method a bit further by showing uniform integrability from which $L^{1}$ convergence will follow. But unfortunately, not enough for almost sure convergence. You have to bring in Martingales or atleast the Maximal inequality(can be proved without martingales) to conclude a.s. convergence as I did in my answer.